# Why Jackson create each Serializer/Deserializer instance for @JsonSerializer/@JsonDeserializer annotated class

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I used Jackson Json Libraries with SpringBoot

When i use @JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class) in severals DTO class Field

- CustomSerializer has no-args constructor with "initialized" logging command

Jackson create Serializer instance for Each DTO class on Json Serialize Process.

how can i create Serializer single instance, and share this.

is it right thinking?

```
    public class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {

        public CustomSerializer() {
            super();
            log.info("initialize : {}", this);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
            gen.writeString("Custom-" + value);
        }

    }
```